# visual studio 'cmd.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I'm trying to use Visual Studio (Enterprise 2017) + CMake (with Ninja) as IDE on Windows.
the CMake Cache is properly generated but I have an error when I try to run the custom target:

```
ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(build_binaries COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build .)
```

All my .c files are built one by one but at the end I get the following error:

```
'cmd.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

Calling `cmake.exe --build .` directly produces the expected result.

Comment: What is the value of `CMAKE_COMMAND`? You can find out by printing a message, which will be printed during the next cmake configuration. `message(STATUS "CMAKE_COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND}")`

Comment: Also, what command do you use to build/run the custom target?

Comment: I use "MY_CMAKE_PATH/cmake.exe --build ." to build my configuration. ${CMAKE_COMMAND} holds the values to my cmake.exe (the one given with Visual Studio)